# Angular ui grid from json files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to load data in one ui grid table from two json files, but there are data only from one file.

I've prepared two arrays for the both json files.

```
$scope.sourceOne = [];
$scope.sourceTwo = [];
```

Then I've loaded data with `$http` service

```
$http.get('SourceOne.json').success(function (data) {
    data.forEach( function( row, index ) {
        $scope.sourceOne.push(data);
    });
    $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
    console.log('data from SourceOne.json', data);
});

$http.get('SourceTwo.json').success(function (data) {
    data.forEach( function( row, index ) {
        $scope.sourceTwo.push(data);
    });
    $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
    console.log('data from SourceTwo.json', data);
});
```

and at the I've tried to concatenate these two arrays and show as a result in the grid.

```
$scope.myConcatenatedData = $scope.sourceOne.concat($scope.sourceTwo);
```

Pls take a look at the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/veYUGRZK69xq9Vlz2pGf?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly there is an erron in the forEach loops (`row` as data item inside loop):

```
data.forEach( function( row, index ) {
    $scope.sourceOne.push(row);
});
```

and then you have to be sure that 2nd data group is loaded after the first one.

Besides concatenation of two data set must be after 2nd group is loaded, inside success handler.

Check my edited Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/tZ1kPgNGiceTfWcrQm2y?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I managed to load a ui grid like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('territories.json').then(function (response) {
        scope.myData = response.data;
    });
});
```